# jQuery custom function to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently write this in **jQuery**

```
$.fn.my_cus_fn = function(){
    $(this.selector).click(function(e) {
        // do stuff
    });
    $(this.selector).focus(function(e) {
        // do stuff
    });
    // ................    
}
```

Then I used it like.

```
$('#my_action1').my_cus_fn();
$('.my_action2').my_cus_fn();
```

I wanted to write it using **javascript** only.

I didn't find any solutin for it. Can anyone help me?

Expecting something like

```
document.getElementById('my_action1').my_cus_fn();
```

Comment: `$('#my_action1')` IS jQuery. do you want this in plain Javascript too?

Comment: @Banana Yes in plain Javascript

Comment: Code using jQuery ***is*** "plain JavaScript." jQuery is a library, not a language. You mean "using the DOM directly."

Comment: I know that jQuery is a JavaScript library. I need to know how to write function similar to that one without any help of "jQuery"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the prototype of elements on nearly all browsers (even IE8, and I think it's *all* modern ones; doesn't work on IE6, not sure about IE7, but those are dead now anyway). Like this:

```
var ElementConstructor = window.Element || window.HTMLElement;
ElementConstructor.prototype.my_cus_fn = function() {
    // Your code here
};
```

The [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) library does this (it's how it got its name). Just beware that you could conflict with other people doing it, and/or with new features added to elements by newer specs. So I'd probably use some kind of likely-to-be-unique prefix on your function names. (FWIW, some years back before significant development on Prototype ended I know the then-maintainers were seriously thinking of not doing prototype extension anymore in favor of wrapping instead, the way jQuery does.)

[Complete Example](http://jsbin.com/fapejeja/1):

```
<div id="foo">This is the element</div>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    var ElementConstructor = window.Element || window.HTMLElement;
    ElementConstructor.prototype.my_cus_fn = function() {
      this.style.color = "green";
    };

    document.getElementById("foo").my_cus_fn();
  })();
</script>
```

If you're going to do a number of extensions, I'd probably wrap them in a scoping function like this, and give the functions proper names (because of the [IE8 problem with named function expressions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html), I use function declarations):

```
(function(ctor) {
    var p = ctor.prototype;

    p.my_cus_fn = my_cus_fn;
    function my_cus_fn() { /* ... */ }

    p.my_other_fn = my_other_fn;
    function my_other_fn() { /* ... */ }

})(window.Element || window.HTMLElement);
```

Comment: _[Using the above code, created something similar to what the OP asked...](http://jsfiddle.net/cRAR5/)_

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : why did you write the function inside (function() {}) ? Is that important?? I can run without it.

Comment: @ArjunRaj: Purely to wrap the contents so I can have private stuff in there, and as a convenient way to pass in the `ctor`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  This is enough for me. But this doesn't work with ` document.getElementsByClassName() ` ( It returns an array of elements ) . If you know how to do this, please share. It will help someone in someday.

Comment: @ArjunRaj: Well, it works for the *elements* in the collection you get back, but yes, it doesn't work for adding methods to the collection *itself*. On most browsers, you can do that by extending `NodeList.prototype`, but that doesn't work on IE8 (I don't know about IE9+). Side note: Don't use `getElementsByClassName`, it's not well-supported. Use `querySelectorAll` instead. It's in all modern browsers (including IE8+).